# Mediawiki templates that know what section (or subsection) they're in?

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-templates

A Mediawiki template can use [Magic Words](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help:Magic_words) to identify what page it's being transcluded into: `{{PAGENAME}}` — and various other details of its namespace. What I can't find out is if there's a Magic Word or some other technique to identify what *section* (or subsection) of the page* it's being transcluded into.

**i.e.* what the headings and subheadings (used to compile the page's table of contents) closest above it are.

Comment: I am afraid, there is no way to do that, as not only the whole page can be parsed but also any of its sections separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Templates need to be context-independent. Currently there are ways to work around that, so you could probably create an extension doing this, but it wouldn't survive the ongoing [parser rewrite](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Parsing/Parser_Unification).